# Excel VBA, crashes while comparing two columns in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have this problem I'd like to compare two columns in one worksheet to another two columns in other worksheet and then if it's true fill other column with data.
I wrote some code but it worked only till 47 row. don't know the problem. Excel is not responding. Here's my code. Maybe someone can shed some light on what I did wrong

```
  Sub Compare()
      Dim i, j As Integer
      For i = 2 To 2175
          For j = 2 To 3834

              If (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("B" & i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz3").Range("A" & j) _
              And ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("C" & i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz3").Range("B" & j)) _
              Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz2").Range("E" & i).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz3").Range("C" & j).Value

          Next j
      Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Small note - when you say "Dim i, j As Integer", Excel doesn't recognize that i is an integer, so it defaults to the generic variable type which holds different kinds of data. You have basically said "Dim i As Variant, Dim j as Integer". You must be explicit, and say "Dim i As Integer, J As Integer". Also - please note how I have reformatted your code, to show more clearly the logical layout of the For statements - previously, it was hard to tell immediately that the Next j / Next i closed those For loops.

Comment: I think you should give it sometime before it finishes. I don't see any reason for it to crash besides taking long time to finish the process. See how you can optimize [For Loop](http://xmlpress.net/2011/09/12/optimizing-vba-part-two/) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I added comments on the lines below where I made changes.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim i as Integer, j As Integer
    ' You need to specify the value type for *all* variables

    Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz2")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz3")
    ' Setting these as their own variables makes the code far more readable

   For i = 2 To 2175
       For j = 2 To 3834

           If (ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value _
              And ws1.Range("C" & i).Value = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value) Then 
              ' Make sure you are comparing the VALUES and not the range objects

              ws1.Range("E" & i).Value = ws2.Range("C" & j).Value

              Exit For    
              ' If we've found a match, exit the inner loop early (if it *would* find 
              ' another match, the orig. value would just be overwritten, anyways) 
              ' This will likely reduce the time to complete significantly
            End If

        Next j
     Next i

End Sub
```

---

<sub>**Edit**: Added the `Exit For` to quit the inner loop early after a match has been found. Credit to [@Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) for the suggestion.</sub>

Comment: I suggest to add something like `If i Mod 100 = 0 Then Debug.Print i` to the outer loop. This will give some progress feedback in the Immediate window (that's 8M loop cycles!)

Comment: @Andre : Good suggestion about adding the loop counter to the outer loop. There is almost ***certainly*** a faster and more efficient way of doing this than the nested `For` loop they are using... but it's really difficult to suggest any alternative approaches without having a better understanding of the data they're actually working with and what they are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're comparing 2173 * 3832 = 8'326'936 cells of data.... no wonder this might crush... ever heard of office cache? Can run out sometimes...

Comment: `Exit For` in the inner loop after you find a match would help: no need to process the following j values...